# Is $2k-1 \nmid (k-1)(k-2)$ true for all positive integers $k>2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove or disprove that for all integers $k>2$:

> $2k-1 \not\mid (k-1)(k-2)$

Using computer I've verified it for all integers less than 10000000, but I am not sure whether it holds for all positive integers or not.

Comment: Show that $2k-1$ and $k-1$ are relatively prime, and thus to find an example, you'd have to have $2k-1\mid k-2$.

Comment: @anon Yeah, I edited. You don't need that they are relatively prime once you need $2k-1\mid k-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \ 2k\!-\!1\mid(2k\!-\!2)(2k\!-\!4)\iff 2k\!-\!1\mid 3,\ $ by $\ {\rm mod}\ 2k\!-\!1\!:\ (2k\!-\!2)(2k\!-\!4)\equiv (-1)(-3)$

i.e. it's just $\,n\mid(n - 1)(n - 3)\iff n\mid 3,\ $ when $\ n = 2k\!-\!1.$

Answer (score 6):

Outline: Show that $2k-1$ and $k-1$ are relatively prime.

Then use that if $a\mid bc$ and $a,b$ relatively prime, then $a\mid c$.

Finally, show that if $k>2$ then $2k-1\not\mid k-2$.

Comment: Euclid is overkill: $ $ in *any* ring: $\ 2k\!-\!1\mid \color{#c00}{(k\!-\!1)n}\,\Rightarrow\,2k\!-\!1\mid n = (2k\!-\!1 - 2\color{#c00}{(k\!-\!1)})\,\color{#c00}n\ \ $

Comment: Well, my argument is just noting $2k-1-2(k-1)=1$ then multiplying by $n$ so, yeah :) @BillDubuque

Comment: Yeah, that's a special case of a proof of Euclid's Lemma using the Bezout Identity (which here is obvious, since one is $\equiv 1$ mod the other, i.e. $\,2k-1\equiv 1\!\pmod{k-1}.\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that

$$2k-1 |k^2-3k+2$$
Then
$$2k-1 | 4(k^2-3k+2)=4k^2-12k+8=(2k-1)(2k-5)+3$$
and hence

$$2k-1 |3$$

Comment: Dear N.S., I think "$\cdots + 2$" should read "$\cdots + 3$".  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Ty, I guess I should go to sleep...

Comment: Aldo, better to us "\mid" rather than "|" - it spaces better.

Answer (score 0):

Let integer $d>0$ divides $\displaystyle 2k-1, (k-1)(k-2)=k^2-3k+2$

Then $d$ divides $\displaystyle k(2k-1)-2(k^2-3k+2)=5k-4$

Then $d$ divides $\displaystyle5(2k-1)-2(5k-4)=3\implies 2k-1$ must divide $3$